# C++ Win32, Unhanded exception access violating writing

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

I've got the following code:

```
    TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("HellowWin");

    TCHAR *trTemp = L" ";
    *trTemp= szAppName[5];
```

Basically what I'm doing here is I'm trying to assign the "value" at index 5 of the `szAPPName` to replace the value represented by the pointer `trTemp`, but I'm getting an access violation error.

Any Ideas?

Below you can see the full code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShoe)
{
        TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("HellowWin");

        TCHAR *trTemp = L" ";
        *trTemp= szAppName[5];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String literals are read-only. Writing to them is undefined behavior. When you assign a string literal to a pointer, you should add `const`.

```
const wchar_t *trTemp = L" ";
```

If you want to write into the variable, declare it as an array so that it holds a copy of the contents of the string literal, and thus writable

```
wchar_t trTemp[] = L" ";
```

(Please use explicitly `wchar_t` instead of those macros.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm using an old book. It seams to like the TCHAR notation.

Answer (score 2):

```
TCHAR *trTemp = L" ";
```

Assigns `trTemp` to point to a constant. That constant will be somewhere in the code segment. When you then try and overwrite it the O/S doesn't like it.

```
TCHAR trTemp[2]={L' ',L'\0'};
```

Should see you right.